# Is there a way to keep the Google Analytics connection open for longer?

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, single-page-application

I have a website where users can spend a long time browsing. It is a SPA. I've added google analytics, and everything works fine for a while, it tracks the number of active users. But after 10 minutes it stops reporting the number of active users even if they are still on the website. Is there a way to keep it from doing this because it is affecting my metrics as I cannot track the average session duration?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't affect your metrics.

From documentation (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1638637?hl=en), in Real Time report of Google Analytics, the active users are those who have sent a hit to Analytics within the last 5 minutes. However the session lasts at least 30 minutes (unless you have changed the value in administration).